# How to change background color of the specific TableRow from tablelayout?

Tags: android

I want change the background color of specific table row from the table layout.
And my tablerow contains three textview in each row. But it throws exception java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow

```
  barcodeid.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count)
        {               
            if(!s.equals("") )
            {   
              String s1 = s.toString();
                    int s2 = Integer.parseInt(s1);                  

                    for(int i=0;i<barcode.length;i++)
                    {                       
                        if(s2 == barcode[i])
                        {                                               
                            TableRow row = (TableRow) tv.getChildAt(barcode[i]);                                                        
                            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);                                                                                                    
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

//This is how i added row in tablerow

```
   TableRow data_row=new TableRow(DbselectActivity.this);
  data_row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,     TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

   TextView b4=new TextView(DbselectActivity.this); 
   b4.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);                                  
   b4.setText(String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("BarcodeId")));
   barcode[i]= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("BarcodeId")));
   b4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   b4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
   b4.setTextSize(20);
   data_row.addView(b4);

                                TextView b5=new TextView(DbselectActivity.this);
                                b5.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b5.setTextSize(20);
                                b5.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));                                   
                                b5.setText(String.valueOf(json_data.getString("ProductName")));
                                b5.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                data_row.addView(b5);

                                TextView b6=new TextView(DbselectActivity.this);
                                b6.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);                                 
                                b6.setText(String.valueOf(json_data.getString("ProductType")));
                                b6.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                b6.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                b6.setTextSize(20);
                                data_row.addView(b6);

                                tv.addView(data_row);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the output for your current code ? Make sure that your TextViews are not overlaying your TableRow view and just hiding the background set by the above code.

Comment: I have dynamically added Textview to tablerow and it throws java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow exception. please help

Comment: Post the complete code.

Comment: i have added full code please see and help me.

Comment: When i put TableRow row = (TableRow) tv.getChildAt(0);                                                        
           row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);      it gives the value of the textview = "BarcodeId" beacause it is static textview. When i put TableRow row = (TableRow) tv.getChildAt(1);                                                        
           row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);                       then it throws classcastexception that view can't converted to tablerow.